# Linux crash causes when runnning my python code

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, crash, python-3.8

#### Problems

Recently, my coworker upgraded our shared desktop PC, increasing its RAM memory from 64GB to 128GB. Since then, I've been experiencing crashes when running some of my Python code. Surprisingly, the desktop PC, equipped with 128GB of the memory and 16 CPUs, only utilizes less than 40GB during these runs. Strangely, my laptop PC, which has 16GB of RAM memory, executes the Python script without any issues. I'm puzzled and eager to understand the problem with the desktop PC.

Below, you'll find examples of the code that caused the crashes, both in a terminal and in a Jupyter notebook.

#### Crashed codes

###### In a terminal

```
cellbender remove-background \
--input /home/owner/mnt/DATA/raw_feature_bc_matrix.h5 \
--output /home/owner/mnt/DATA/cellbender_output.h5 \
--expected-cells 12044 \
--total-droplets-included 15000 \
--fpr 0.01 \
--epochs 150
```

###### In a jupyter notebook

```
n_pcs = 50
import pdb

def your.function():
    pca_model = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components=n_pcs)
    pca_model.fit(df_adata.values.T)

cumulative_variance_ratio = np.cumsum(pca_model.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

```
meta_data = adata.obs
data_mat = adata.obsm['X_pca']
import harmonypy as hm
ho = hm.run_harmony(data_mat, meta_data, 'experiment')
```

#### The specs of the desktop pc

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Memory　125.7 GiB
Processor　Intel® Xeon(R) E-2288G CPU @ 3.70GHz × 16
Graphics　Radeon RX 570 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-150-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)
GNOME　3.28.2
Type of OS　64 bit
Disk　502.9 GB

#### The version of my conda env

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| python | 3.8.16 |
| cellbender | 0.2.2 |
| matplotlib | 3.4.2 |
| numpy | 1.24.3 |
| pandas | 1.4.1 |
| scanpy | 1.9.1 |
| harmonypy | 0.0.5 |
| scikit-learn | 1.2.2 |
| jupyter | 1.0.0 |

---

#### Things I have tried

My coworker mentioned that his R script ran perfectly on the desktop PC, which led me to suspect that the issue might be related to an incompatible Conda package version. Consequently, I replicated the same Conda environment as the one on my laptop PC onto the desktop PC, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the problem. I even attempted to limit the memory usage to 32GB, but that also proved unsuccessful.

Comment: What do you mean by _crashed_?

Comment: 'Crashed' means that the pc shut down suddenly without displaying errors while running the python script.